# virtualbox bridged adaptor works only guest->host but not host->guest

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, arp

I have virtualbox 4.1 on a ubuntu 12.04 host. On my host I have a virtual interface eth0:1 configurend as 10.0.1.1. I have a few virtual machines using bridged adapters, configured in the 10.0.1.0 net which I can reach (ping, ssh, ...) from my host via the virtual interface.

Now I installed an ubuntu server 12.04 in a virtual box, again using bridged adapter, but I can not reach that host. The strange thing is I can reach my host from my guest, e.g. ssh from guest to host works well. So I am sure the virtual cable is pluged.
But my host does not even know about the mac of that virtual machine:

```
~$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
butterbier                       (incomplete)                              eth0
debian                   ether   08:00:27:b7:c0:8a   C                     eth0
```

The machine called "debian" has the same "hardware" setup in virtualbox as "butterbier", but "butterbier" is not reachable. The only difference in "hardware" is the container. For "butterbier" I chose VMDK (as I am planning to import into Vmware later), whearas the other machines use VDI.

I also tried to set the mac manually in /etc/ethers, but no success.

What might be the cause? What can I do?